# Android Studio genymotion emulator not running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion along with Android Studio using the plug-in and no matter what I do it does not allow me to run the app using the Genymotion emulator.. it gives errors like this:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: genymotion-samsung_galaxy_s4___4_4_2___api_19___1080x1920-192.168.56.101:5555
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\zd\AndroidStudioProjects\funfacts2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/Taha.funfacts2
Installing Taha.funfacts2
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/Taha.funfacts2"
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Taha.funfacts2
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

This is running on just a test app that outputs Hello World on the screen, with some basic formatting.

Comment: Have you tried it on different "genymotion devices"?

Comment: Can you paste your manifest file?